# Boto3 generate_presigned_url, SignatureDoesNotMatch error

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

Several questions and answers on SO and elsewhere have outlined possible solutions for resolving the SignatureDoesNotMatch error thrown when calling 'generate_presigned_url' from the boto3 SDK. Few are in boto3 and most answers suggest getting new credentials to resolve this exception. You can see more (but this is in PHP) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-signature-er).

But these do not work for me, because I am using correct credentials and the correct bucket name and key path.

Originally, I was calling this to generate my client and then call generate_presigned_url.

```
client_s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    # Hard coded strings as credentials, not recommended.
    aws_access_key_id='XXX',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXX',
    region_name='us-east-2',
    # EDIT: Previously, I used signature_version='v4' here, but as a user here pointed out, this might not work. Regardless, I tried 's3v4' prior to trying 'v4' and neither worked for me.
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)

url = client_s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'BUCKET_NAME',
        'Key': 'CORRECT_KEY'
    }
)
```

What could create this error when all of the parameters used are seemingly correct? How do I resolve it?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After seeing this [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=234825), I figured something fishy might be going on, but I really just wanted to resolve the issue with a secure solution.

My resolution is definitely not optimal for everyone, but it worked for me.

I copied everything from my bucket in 'us-east-2' into a new bucket in 'us-east-1' and I was able to access that bucket correctly with the exact same access/secret keys and bucket/key paths. I simply used:

```
client_s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    # Hard coded strings as credentials, not recommended.
    aws_access_key_id='XXX',
    aws_secret_access_key='XXX'
)
```

If you're like me and don't want to spend hours trying to decipher AWS's poor docs, just do this if you can. If you have a *real* solution, please add it here.

I still am unsure what causes this, but likely has something to do with the 'v4' signing method, which is region-dependent.

Comment: To the two downvoters --- easy to downvote, but realize first I posted the question and answer before any existed for the purpose of helping. My answer, while suboptimal, was the *only* answer at the time. If you have feedback, post it here.

Answer (score 7):

It is clearly mentioned in the [documentation of boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#configuration) that the option should look like `config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')`. `v4` wouldn't work.

This is an example of boto3 documentation.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

# Get the service client with sigv4 configured
s3 = boto3.client('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))

# Generate the URL to get 'key-name' from 'bucket-name'
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'bucket-name',
        'Key': 'key-name'
    }
)
```

---

Btw, `us-east-2` only allow signature verion 4 and so you don't need to specify that. [See This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region).

Comment: Hi, I used that as well, and later changed it to v4 after I saw another user tried 'v4' instead. Both did not work for me. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: your original region don't need to specify the signature version, cuz v4 is default and only option for that.

Comment: Yup, it does not work without specification of the signature version either.

Comment: Then, please check your bucket location by dong `client_s3.get_bucket_location(Bucket='string')`.

Comment: Furthermore, try to use the config `Config(s3={'addressing_style': 'path'})`. What version of boto3 are u using?

Comment: The bucket is definitely in us-east-2, and the most recent version of boto3. I just don't want to debug the problem because it has been solved, but thank you and +1 for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late to answer, but I solved my problem by following the method as specified in [this](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/934) GitHub link.

```
import boto3
import requests

parts = s3_client.generate_presigned_post(Bucket=bucket_name,
                                          Key=key,
                                          Fields={
                                            'acl': 'public-read',
                                            'Content-MD5': str(md5),
                                            'Content-Type': 'binary/octet-stream'
                                            },
                                          Conditions=[
                                              {"acl": "public-read"},
                                              ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
                                              ["starts-with", "$Content-MD5", ""]
                                          ]
                                      )

url = parts['url']
data = parts['fields']
files = {'file': open(local_path, 'rb')} # the key supposed to be file may be
response = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but I have a solution that works for me and I anticipate it may work for others.

```
    s3_client: Session = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        aws_access_key_id=kwargs["aws_access_key_id"],
        aws_secret_access_key=kwargs["aws_secret_access_key"],
        config=Config(
            signature_version="s3v4",
            region_name="us-east-2",
        ),
    )

    response: str = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
        "put_object",
        Params={"Bucket": "example-bucket", "Key": "subfolder/file_name.zip"},
        ExpiresIn=expiration,
    )
```

The response will contain the pre-signed URL.  I then take the URL and paste it into Postman to test it out and make sure you use PUT instead of POST and add your file as a binary payload.  I've tested and verified this method.