# AWS Cognito signature mismatch issue after aspnetcore upgrade from 1.0 to 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, amazon-cognito

After upgrading Dotnet core framework from 1.0 to 2.1 the AWS Cognito calls are failing to give a Signature mismatch error. The same calls if connected with the old framework (1.0) code is still working.

Like the following call:

```
var request = new ListUsersInGroupRequest();
request.GroupName = groupName;
request.Limit = 60;
request.UserPoolId = _configuration.GetSection(Utility.AWS).GetSection(Utility.AWSUserPoolId).Value;

var output = _cognitoIdentityClient.ListUsersInGroupAsync(request).Result;
```

is throwing the following error:

> System.AggregateException HResult=0x80131500 Message=One or more
>   errors occurred. (The request signature we calculated does not match
>   the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and
>   signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.)
>   Source=System.Private.CoreLib StackTrace: at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification) at
>   WDP.Services.UserService.ListUsersInGroupAsync(String groupName) in
>   C:\Users\arupc\source\WDP\Projects\WDP\WDP.Services\UserService.cs:line
>   631 at WDP.Services.UserService.GetUsers(User loggedUser) in
>   C:\Users\arupc\source\WDP\Projects\WDP\WDP.Services\UserService.cs:line
>   194 at WDP.Lambda.Controllers.UserController.GetAllUsers() in
>   C:\Users\arupc\source\WDP\Projects\WDP\WDP.AWSServerless\Controllers\UserController.cs:line
>   58 at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
>   target, Object[] parameters) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__12.MoveNext()
>
> This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
>   Amazon.Runtime.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponseAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken)
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
>
> Inner Exception 1: AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderException: The request
>   signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
>   Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the
>   service documentation for details.
>
> Inner Exception 2: HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type
>   'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 - How to fix 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/aws-s3-how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-sign)

Comment: No, the error that I am getting is caused by incompatible dlls.

Answer (score 0):

The signature mismatch issue that I was getting was caused by the following issue:

"Amazon.Lambda.DynamoDBEvents" Version="1.1.0" dll was not compatible with "AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider" Version="3.3.4" dll or above.

And the solution is to downgrade the Amazon.Lambda.DynamoDBEvents version from 1.1.0 to 1.0.0.