# S3Exception with AWS SDK for Java version 2 - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am trying to get list of object in an S3 bucket using `AWS SDK for Java version 2`.
Getting following exception:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: 
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
Check your key and signing method. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: DCE23DE2BC35653C)
```

**My code snippet:**

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsSessionCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
....
private software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client getS3Client(Region region) {
    //Getting values from properties file -- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
    AwsSessionCredentials awsCreds =
        AwsSessionCredentials.create(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN);
    S3Client s3 =
        S3Client.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
            .build();
    return s3;
}

public void listObjects(Region region, String bucketName) {
    S3Client s3 = getS3Client(region);
    ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest
          .builder()
          .bucket(bucketName)
          .build();
    ListObjectsResponse res = s3.listObjects(listObjects); // This throws S3Exception
    List<S3Object> objects = res.contents();
    ....
    //Iterate over 'objects' and do something
}
```

**pom.xml entries:**

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: DCE23DE2BC35653C)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleErrorResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:115)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:73)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:58)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:41)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:64)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:36)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(RetryableStage.java:113)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:86)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:240)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:96)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:120)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73)
software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44)
software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55)
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.listObjects(DefaultS3Client.java:2278)
com.mycompany.test.MyS3Driver.listObjects(MyS3Driver.java:44)
```

I have verified my AWS Credentials and my account has PowerUser access.
I Looked at following links but it didn't help as I am using 'AwsSessionCredentials' class

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30519762/948268 -- Mentions about key starting with a period.
2. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/86 -- Talks about Ensuring proper encoding of URI query string parameter-values. but in my case I am using [AwsSessionCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/credentials.html) class.

Also posted the issue on: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1767

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, the issue was with the bucket name that was passed. It included the folder name in addition to bucket name. It was `<BUCKET_NAME>/<FOLDER_NAME>` that caused the issue. After passing just the `<BUCKET_NAME>` it worked fine.

Comment: Thank you! I had a same problem.

Comment: Glad it helped.