# How to access S3 bucket through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've looked at some other posts and tried to replicate what they've done, but none of them seem to be running into the same issue I am. Basically, I'm trying to store the list of keys from a S3 bucket so I can iterate through them in my Vue app. I've got the code below, and you can see I have 3 `console.log` statements where I'm trying to print the value of `files`. The first one prints exactly what I expect it to, while the 2nd one prints `[]`, and the 3rd doesn't print at all. So for some reason it's not persisting the value of `files` outside of the `s3.listObjectsV2()` function, which means I can't access the actual files themselves in the app.

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.VUE_APP_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.VUE_APP_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: "us-east-1",
});
let s3 = new AWS.S3();

let params = {
  Bucket: "my-bucket",
  Delimiter: "",
};

let getS3Files = () => {
  let files = [];
  s3.listObjectsV2(params, function (err, data) {
    if (data) {
      data.Contents.forEach((file) => {
        files.push({
          fileName: file.Key,
          fileDate: file.LastModified,
        });
      });
      console.log(files);
    }
  });
  console.log(files);
  if (files.length > 0) {
    files = files.sort((a, b) => b.fileDate - a.fileDate);
    console.log(files);
  }
  return files;
};

getS3Files();
```

Comment: I think the behavior is given by the way you check if data has values. Please instead of `if (data) {...}` try `if (Object.keys(data).length > 0) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are not waiting until the `s3.listObjectsV2` completes fetching its data. Although `s3.listObjectsV2` does not seem like a function you should wait until it completes, it needs time to send a request to `s3` and get the data you requested.

In the code you provided, the second `console.log` will most probably execute before the first `console.log` and by that time you would not have any data pushed to `files`. Hence it will print `[]`. And before the third log, it is checking whether you have any element in your `files` which would again equal to `false` since `files = []`.

So, you need to wrap this around a Promise and wait until it completes.

```js
let getS3Files = async () => {
  let files = [];

  await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    s3.listObjectsV2(params, function (err, data) {
      if (data) {
        data.Contents.forEach((file) => {
          files.push({
            fileName: file.Key,
            fileDate: file.LastModified,
          });
        });
        console.log(files);
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
  console.log(files);
  if (files.length > 0) {
    files = files.sort((a, b) => b.fileDate - a.fileDate);
    console.log(files);
  }
  return files;
};

await getS3Files();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the s3 api, but I understand `listObjectsV2` is an asynchronous operation, in consequence `files` will be empty because it happens outside the asynchronous call and is executed before having values

Please try

```
let AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.update({
  accessKeyId: process.env.VUE_APP_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.VUE_APP_ACCESS_KEY,
  region: "us-east-1",
});

let s3 = new AWS.S3();
let params = {
  Bucket: "my-bucket",
  Delimiter: "",
};

let getS3Files = (callback) => {
  s3.listObjectsV2(params, function (err, data) {
    callback(data);
  });
};

getS3Files((data) => {
  const files = data.Contents.map((file) => ({
    fileName: file.key,
    fileDate: file.LastModified,
  })).sort((a, b) => b.fileDate - a.fileDate);

  return files;
});
```

In this case, the `getS3Files` receives a callback that will contain the data, which you will process in the function call.

Take a look to this question [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: It seems like this works perfectly fine if I put a `console.log` above the `return files` and call the function from the terminal, but if I try to import and reference the function from inside the Vue app, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Contents' of null`.

Comment: Please add `if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); return; }` before `callback(data);` in order to identify the error reason

Comment: Actually getting a mix of different errors now.
The first is  


`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _s3Data__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default(...) is not a function"`
and the second is  


`SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.`
which looks like an issue with grabbing the data from S3.

Comment: About `SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.` take a look to this answer and comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/30519762/615274 could be relevant

Comment: I came across that earlier and I wish it was that easy. I only have 1 file in the bucket right now and it's `MOVIE.mp4`.