# AWS S3 - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have been having a problem for almost 3 months
I am using the react-s3 lib to upload files to AWS S3. I need to provide my bucket name, id and pw (normal). It used to work fine but since about June it doesn't work anymore and I have this error: "The signature of the request we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."
I tried everything tried everything, nothing works (change lib, generate new key...)

Comment: Your credentials may have expired. Generate new ones

Comment: @TasosBu I have already try to generate new id and key

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/aws-s3-how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-sign

Comment: @TasosBu Yes buts it's not fix my problem