# SignatureDoesNotMatch The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: amazon-s3

I got this error when I sent an HTTP post request for uploading files directly from the browser to the AWS s3 bucket. I think the problem is with calculating signature and I am not sure what data/parameters should be used to calculate signature and how signature should be calculated and I am using Django.

`SignatureDoesNotMatch`
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS S3 - How to fix 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/aws-s3-how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-sign)

Answer (score 0):

In my case was the aws credentials and secret. If you using localstack try to put your key and secret 'test'/'test', in my case it works. If not check if your credentials are ok