# Simple PUT operation via presigned URL keep getting error "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided"

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using

```
boto3==1.17.57
```

I have read [AWS S3 - How to fix 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/aws-s3-how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-sign)

But I am not sure why I am still getting

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
> provided. Check your key and signing method.

when I try to perform PUT operation.

My code snippet is pretty straightforward.

```
import requests
import boto3
from botocore.client import ClientError

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket_name = 'cloud-storage-1'
file_name = 'car.jpg'



########
# BUCKET
########
try:
    s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
except ClientError as e:
    print(str(e))
    print("Try to create bucket for the first time")

    s3.create_bucket(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        CreateBucketConfiguration={
            'LocationConstraint': 'eu-central-1'
        }
    )



##################
# GET FILE CONTENT
##################
with open(file_name, 'rb') as object_file:
    body = object_file.read()
object_file.close()



###############
# PRESIGNED URL
###############
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

url = s3_client.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='put_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': bucket_name, 
        'Key': file_name
    },
    ExpiresIn=3600
)

print(url)



#####
# PUT
#####
response = requests.put(url, data=body)

print(response.content)
```

I can confirm the  `~/.aws/credentials` is correct, as I can see the bucket being created with no issue.

### Bucket created without issue

[image]

### ~/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXX
aws_secret_access_key=YYY
region=eu-central-1
```

Does anyone has any idea why it is so?

Comment: What about time? Maybe your system clock is too much different then that of AWS?

Comment: I check the system clock of my Docker system. It looks fine. (I run the Python script in Docker environment). It is weird that this problem just happen randomly. If I tend to clean up entire S3 files and buckets, it will help to resolve the problem sometimes. Or, if I run the script in next morning, it helps too. Not sure why :-(