# Image upload failed using AWS SDK V2 in GO

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I am using AWS S3 service to upload images. Yesterday I updated the SDK v1 to v2 and found that the image upload is failing with the following error:

```
operation error S3: PutObject, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: XXXXXXXXXXX, HostID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, api error SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

**UPDATED**:
I have aws credentials on my home folder in linux in .aws folder in the following format:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
```

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    awsconfig "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/s3/manager"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3"
)

func main() {
    fileName := "test123.jpg"
    filePath := "/BUCKET_NAME/uploads/aman/2021/6/25/"

    res, err := http.Get("https://images.app.goo.gl/mpQ5nXYXjdUMKGgW7")
    if err != nil || res.StatusCode != 200 {
        // handle errors
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    UploadFileInS3Bucket(res.Body, fileName, filePath)
}

func UploadFileInS3Bucket(file io.Reader, fileName, filePath string) {
    cfg, err := awsconfig.LoadDefaultConfig(context.TODO(),
        awsconfig.WithRegion("REGION"),
    )
    client := s3.NewFromConfig(cfg)
    uploader := manager.NewUploader(client)
    uploadResp, err := uploader.Upload(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:      aws.String(filePath),
        Key:         aws.String(fileName),
        Body:        file,
        ContentType: aws.String("image"),
    })
    fmt.Println(uploadResp)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

I did not change any credentials/buckets/regions in my code.However if I run the code with SDK v1 then it works fine & images are uploading.

What is going wrong with the SDK v2 ?

Comment: Could it be a leading slash? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/aws-s3-how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-sign provide a full sample to reptoducce.

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski I have checked this. Leading slash does not seem to be the problem here.

Comment: Publish reproducible sample. It is not clear what are you sending into that function. V2 can be more strict for something.

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski I have added a reproducible example and details about credentials above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending a couple of days, I came to know that SDK V2 takes following format for Bucket & Key field:

```
fileName := "uploads/2021/6/25/test123.jpg"
filePath := "BUCKET_NAME"
```

Basically for these fields there is vice versa behaviour in SDK V1 & V2. Above is the V2. Below is the V1:

```
fileName := "test123.jpg"
filePath := "/BUCKET_NAME/uploads/2021/6/25/"
```

Comment: That actually makes sense.  You are sending now `Bucket  =  "BUCKET_NAME"`. I am sure V1 would accept that as well. SDK is less forgiving now for incorrect data. The error message is misleading though. I understand your confusion.

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski Yes the error message confused me. It should be correctly descriptive.