# Fine Uploader S3: Upload Directly to Amazon S3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Can any one provide few examples on how to upload file **from browser directly to  S3**
using FineUploader https://fineuploader.com/#s3-demo
i dont know  where i am going wrong, can any one help me please , i am using  **ASP.net MVC**
also please correct  me if configuration is wrong
My goal is to upload  file in chunks on s3, file would be aroung 10 gb +

```
        var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
            debug: true,
            element: document.getElementById('uploader'),
            objectProperties: {
                bucket: '***********',
                  region: 'ap-south-1',
                  acl: 'private', 
                },
            request: {
                endpoint: 'https://*******.s3.amazonaws.com/',
                accessKey: '**********************',

            },
              signature: { 
                version: 4,
                endpoint: '/Home/GetMetadataForUploadFile', // This is  returning  {"policy":"***","signature":"q********i"} 
            }, 
            chunking: {
                enabled: true,
                concurrent: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
            resume: {
                enabled: true
            },
            retry: {
               enableAuto: true // defaults to false
            }
        })
    }());
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: @Riz have i done the configuraion right  ?

Comment: sorry I am not sure. It was more for extra information which can help others to understand the issue better. Maybe post the error message in the question.

Comment: i did few tweaks in the configuration now i am getting this exception in console

Comment: util.js:241 [Fine Uploader 5.16.2] Specific problem detected initiating multipart upload request for 0: 'The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. 
Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.'.
qq.log @ util.js:241
log @ uploader.basic.api.js:304
(anonymous) @ util.js:691
n @ multipart.initiate.ajax.requester.js:130
a @ ajax.requester.js:145
(anonymous) @ ajax.requester.js:253
i*******m.s3.amazonaws.com//8f87134a-925e-4ce6-a806-04d7b9cbf284.zip?uploads:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: After adding this  signature: { 
                    endpoint: '/Home/GetMetadataForUploadFile',
                    version: 4
                }, that error went

Comment: Now getting this exception : Specific problem detected initiating multipart upload request for 0: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.'

Comment: check this thread and see if you have any of these cases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/amazon-s3-how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-s?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top