# specifying the signature version of s3 client in aws sdk version 3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

In `aws-sdk v2` for javascript, we instantiate s3 client using:

```
var s3  = new AWS.S3({
          accessKeyId: 'YOUR-ACCESSKEYID' ,
          secretAccessKey: 'YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY' ,
          s3ForcePathStyle: true,
          signatureVersion: 'v4'
});
```

Here you can see the `signatureVersion` being able to be specified.

In `v3` you instantiate the client using:

```
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3';

credentials = {  
    accessKeyId: <ACCESS_KEY>,
    secretAccessKey: <SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
  }
const client = new S3Client({
        region: 'us-east-1',
        credentials: credentials,
        forcePathStyle: true,
    })
```

The docs aren't very clear (and without an example) on how to do this. How would I specify the `signatureVersion` for the client in this versin(v3) of the sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just migrated from the old to new s3 client.

I previously *had* to specify `signatureVersion: 'v4'` [because of this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56938973/9362404) (we had to upload files with whitespaces).

I have not had this issue since migrating, so I think it's safe to assume they use version 4 signatures by default.

And since they don't expose a `signatureVersion` config option, I would say it's also safe to assume you *can't* use signature version 2 using the the new SDK.

--

*[Edit]* Check their docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/bucket-policy-s3-sigv4-conditions.html

```
"AWS" identifies Signature Version 2

"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" identifies Signature Version 4
```

So you should be able to check the `X-Amz-Algorithm` query param to make sure.