# Use Node js @aws-sdk/client-s3 Using AWS CLI Credentials from .env Only

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, node-modules

Nodejs Project with media stored in S3 Bucket and Using `@aws-sdk/client-s3` as an AWS SDK Client. `.env` and  `S3Bucket.js` are as Below.

**.env in the Project root directory:**

```
AWS_ACCESSKEYID = AHMXXXXXXXXXXH
AWS_SECRETKEY = fdgggdgdmcxvxcvbvfdgffgfs
AWS_REGION = ap-south-1
```

**Configurations of  `S3Bucket.js` :**

```
const { S3Client, PutObjectCommand, DeleteObjectCommand, HeadObjectCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')
const s3 = new S3Client({ accessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESSKEYID, secretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRETKEY, signatureVersion: 'v4', region: config.AWS_REGION })
```

But Still, It is Using the Credentials of local aws credentials, which Means It is using aws-cli creds from `~/.aws/credentials`. Instead, It Should use the AWS Credentials from `.env` Only.

```
CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
at  /node_modules/@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node/dist-cjs/defaultProvider.js:13:11
at  /node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/chain.js:12:39
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async coalesceProvider ( /node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/memoize.js:14:24)
at async SignatureV4.credentialProvider ( /node_modules/@smithy/property-provider/dist-cjs/memoize.js:33:24)
at async SignatureV4.signRequest ( /node_modules/@smithy/signature-v4/dist-cjs/SignatureV4.js:106:29)
at async  /node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist-cjs/awsAuthMiddleware.js:16:18
at async  /node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/retryMiddleware.js:27:46
at async  /node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/region-redirect-endpoint-middleware.js:14:24
at async  /node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/region-redirect-middleware.js:9:20 {
```

I want it to use AWS Credentials from .env and configure this same thing in `S3Bucket.js` also. but it is fetching creds from `~/.aws/credentials`.

Comment: Have you tried logging your variables? `config.AWS_ACCESSKEYID` etc... ?

Comment: Yes, @LeeroyHannigan, in console.log it is Giving the right AWS Acces and Secret Key I'd

Comment: Hi, if the answer was correct then please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are supplying credentials is incorrect.

Use the following:

```
const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const client = new S3Client({
    region: config.AWS_REGION,
    // signatureVersion: 'v4'
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: config.AWS_ACCESSKEYID,
        secretAccessKey: config.AWS_SECRETKEY
    }
});
```

I'm not 100% sure that's how you would supply signature v4 on the constructor (the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-s3/Class/S3Client/) is less than ideal) but I [believe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791321/specifying-the-signature-version-of-s3-client-in-aws-sdk-version-3) that v4 is the default, so you don't need to explicitly set it (and, conceivably, *cannot* set it).

Comment: Interesting that it accepts parameters which are not valid too 

Comment: @LeeroyHannigan yes, other AWS SDKs do well (alert you to the presence of unexpected parameters) but the v3/TypeScript refresh has hugely complicated the SDK imo and the documentation is beyond challenging to use. For example: start with [S3Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-s3/Class/S3Client/) and try to find where you would indicate v4 signature. Chances are you will not find it, but you'll have to do a lot of hunting & pecking in the process. Would love to see AWS doc writer or SDK owner try this exact thing to see how problematic it is.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. Let me share this internally.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod !! it Works