# Snowflake - Stage area error( signature does not match)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Iam getting this error while copying to snowflake via AWS S3 .

```
copy into ORDER1 from 's3://path' credentials = (aws_secret_key '<secret_key' aws_key_id = '<key_id>');
```

My credential values are correct as far as my knowledge , And my S3 path is also correct, may I know how to rectify the following error?

```
Failure using stage area. Cause: [The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. (Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch)]
```

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/amazon-s3-how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-s

Answer (score 0):

it looks to me like you have a typo in your copy into statement, arent you missing '=' next to aws_secret key?

syntax from docs
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html
is

```
credentials=(aws_key_id='$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID' aws_secret_key='$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
```