# Dotnet Minimal Api deployed as AWS Lambda Http Api with a function url returns 403 when trying to conduct a HttpPost multipart/form-data request

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, file-upload

I'm trying to do a file upload via AWS Lambda Http Api. The deployment is a dotnet 6 minimal api. I have enabled function url, and have a httpget and a httppost method. Both the endpoints work absolutely fine locally. The get endpoint is just a diagnostic one and works fine when called via postman. But for the post (which is a file upload) I get a 403.[image]

And this is the get which uses the exact same credentials and works absolutely fine.
[image]

If I debug locally I'm able to upload files via a console app and even postman, but once I deploy it, I just get 403. This is what the code looks like

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileAsync([FromForm]RetailerUploadDetailsDto request)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await _fileService.UploadFileAsync(request.File.FileName, _webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName, request.File.OpenReadStream().ToByteArray());
        if (result.IsError)
        {
            return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result.Error);
        }
        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, "Failed to upload file");
        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e.Message);
    }
}
```

The curl request for the httpget

```
curl --location 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws/Upload/Diagnostic' --header 'X-Amz-Date: 20231017T031151Z' --header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxx/20231017/ap-southeast-2/lambda/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

The curl request for httppost

```
curl --location 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws/Upload' --header 'X-Amz-Date: 20231017T031710Z' --header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxx/20231017/ap-southeast-2/lambda/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' --form 'RetailerId=""' --form 'ShouldDeleteProducts="false"' --form 'File=@"/path/to/file"'
```

Curl Response

```
*  start date: Jan 25 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 24 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws" matched cert's "*.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M01
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/1.x
> POST /Upload HTTP/1.1
> Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> X-Amz-Date: 20231019T065110Z
> Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=xxxxxxxxxxxxx/20231019/ap-southeast-2/lambda/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
> Content-Length: 1199
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------aa32a829b410f448
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Thu, 19 Oct 2023 06:51:40 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 192
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: 15d0355e-1497-4de7-89a5-f965790fc509
< x-amzn-ErrorType: InvalidSignatureException
<
* Connection #0 to host xxxxxxxxxxx.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws left intact
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}%
```

As requested by @saart I tried removing the slash in the curl request,

Here's the request

```
curl --location 'https://***********.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws/Upload' \
--header 'X-Amz-Date: 20231023T193740Z' \
--header 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=*************/ap-southeast-2/lambda/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=*********************' \
--form 'RetailerId=""' \
--form 'ShouldDeleteProducts="false"' \
--form 'File=@"Retailer Upload Sheet_v1.4.xlsx"' -v
```

and this was the response

```
*  start date: Jan 25 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 24 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "************.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws" matched cert's "*.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M01
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/1.x
> POST /Upload HTTP/1.1
> Host: *****************.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws
> User-Agent: curl/8.1.2
> Accept: */*
> X-Amz-Date: 20231023T193740Z
> Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=******************/20231023/ap-southeast-2/lambda/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=*************************************
> Content-Length: 14773
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------d7780c363dd73797
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Mon, 23 Oct 2023 19:38:10 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 192
< Connection: keep-alive
< x-amzn-RequestId: 52022402-4797-44e0-b93d-485d4de7dc8f
< x-amzn-ErrorType: InvalidSignatureException
<
* Connection #0 to host *****************.lambda-url.ap-southeast-2.on.aws left intact
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details."}%
```

Any pointers would help..

Comment: Are you using API Gateway to connect the client to the Lambda function?

Comment: No. Im just using postman for testing. And for the client. I have another api which acts as ApiGateway. Im using AWS Auth. I have other apis which work fine using the same configuration, the only difference is multipart upload here

Comment: There is a related .NET example that shows images uploaded via API Gateway->.NET Lambda -> S3. However this does not appear to be exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: No, Im using a function url with AWS auth

Comment: Are you sure that the role you're assuming with the auth has access to the lambda role? What does cloudwatch say on this?

Comment: Yes the auth works fine, the screenshot above shows a get request

Comment: I cannot see what you're passing as the auth header, nor can I see the full code - please convert your Postman requests to curl requests and then share full information on how you're doing auth. Are you sure the GET request has auth enabled?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I've added the curl requests for both get and post

Comment: And can you remove your Postman screenshots and paste the full output of the curl commands using `curl -v`?

Comment: What's the size of the file you try to upload?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I've added the curl -v response

Comment: @Posio Anywhere between 1 and 500kb atmost 1MB . The file has to be manually generated so I dont think it will ever be huge

Answer (score 0):

This error could happen when the arguments are not normalized, e.g. when the path to the file is relative and starts with `../`.

Check out the first answer and its comments here: [Amazon S3 - How to fix 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518899/amazon-s3-how-to-fix-the-request-signature-we-calculated-does-not-match-the-s)

Comment: This is how I've specified the parameters in the curl request, I dont use relative path and I still get 403

--form 'RetailerId=""' \
--form 'ShouldDeleteProducts="false"' \
--form 'File=@"/Users/madhav/Downloads/Retailer Upload Sheet_v1.4.xlsx"' -v

Comment: Another subcomment in this thread is:
`A leading slash also caused this issue for me. You need just path/to/file, not /path/to/file – ` Can you try it too?

Comment: If I remove the leading slash 

--form 'RetailerId=""' \
--form 'ShouldDeleteProducts="false"' \
--form 'File=@"Users/madhav/Downloads/Retailer Upload Sheet_v1.4.xlsx"' -v
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Comment: Can you copy the file to your working directory, and then use relative path?
I.e. something like `move "/Users/madhav/Downloads/Retailer Upload Sheet_v1.4.xlsx" temp.xlsx`, and then run with `'File=@"temp.xlsx"'`

Comment: Cant post the response here, updating the question.

Comment: try to drop the spaces? Following the thread attached before, my guess is that this is a problem with the file path.

Comment: Renamed the file to Retailer_Upload_Sheet.xlsx. No difference in output